# Show camera feature on iPhone when there is no camera?

Tags: navigation, iphone, tables

In my iPhone app I have a root view with some options, one being a "Camera" option where you can take a photo to send to us. My question is should I either

**A: Show it "grayed out"**
[image]

or **B: Not show it at all**
[image]

I definitely prefer option A, but I am not an expert in design.

Comment: One question, when has there ever not been a camera on the iPhone?

Comment: @Nick - iPhone apps can work on iPods and iPads as well, and first gen of both of those were without cameras.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot about iPod touches and iPads. My mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option B is better for the user of the device at hand. There's no way that device is going to suddenly get a camera on it, so there really isn't a reason to show the user a function that they will never be able to use.

The reason that people recommend graying out options not currently available is so that a user will know that it is there and they could use it under certain conditions. Since there are no such conditions in this case (their device doesn't have a camera), it doesn't make a lot of sense to show it to them.

Comment: +1 for so there really isn't a reason to show the user a function that they will never be able to use

Comment: +1 Agreed. Let's not tease them, just show them what they can do. It would be wrong to disable an option that is restricted by permanent physical constraints with no chance of enabling it ever.

Comment: Great point. I had a strong preference for the grayed-out item (since the user knows the option exists), but your argument is convincing.

Comment: The upper echelons have me going with option A, which I still like. However this is a good argument against it. But to defend our decision half of the functionality of the app is the camera, if they don't have one its a gentle reminder they should buy a new device (or use our android app, they require a camera ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Option A

[image]

[image]

Option A is good practice from usability point of view,if you are using window xp or mac. when a hardware is not available, then options related that hardware is often time disabled. so its good practice to keep them disabled when its hardware is not available.

there is an another option with cross mark, few high profile website is using this option for better user experiences and instructions.

Like

See the below option, you can enable the camera with cross mark. and when user click on video icon so there should be some information like camera not found, you should install it from (some where location).

I use rough images for explanation in this answer, you can replace these images with your iphone images.

[image]

Comment: *Why* is it a good practice from a usability point of view?

Comment: which option , A or B, Read the full answer.  I use rough images for explanation in this answer, you can replace these images with your iphone images.

Comment: @abdul - the option that you said was a good practice; I was essentially quoting what you wrote. You don't give a reason why you believe it is a good practice.

Comment: in option second image there is cross icon used, which show that you can not use camera. and when click then there should be some information . as we are using. its now up to you, how you handle it ... but to be honest we are using like this.

Comment: Why is Usibility point of view?. if you are using window xp or mac. when a hardware is not available, then options related that hardware is often time disabled. so its good practice to keep them disabled when its hardware is not available.

Comment: @abdul - you are stating that the original poster's Option A is good practice from a usability point of view. You do not explain your reasoning for this statement at all. Your comments do not improve that statement.

Comment: we are here to share our ideas with each other, so this is just an idea, if you like it you can use it. other wise ignore it. or vote down.

Comment: @abdul - actually, when a piece of hardware is not available in Windows or MacOS, it does not show that hardware. I don't see anything for a webcam on my computers when I don't have a webcam attached.

Comment: ok let me show you my screen capture.

Comment: @Chrles Boyung, can't you see the attached skype screen. i have not installed webcam, so video call text is disabled.